# CWM - Can I make CWM mount a different External SD Card Partition - LG e400f

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, partitions, lg, stock-rom, lg-optimus

As stated in the title I want to be able to mount my SD cards 3rd Partition, this is because that is were all my files are and I would like to be able to backup to this partition.

Phone: LG e400f

Rooted: Yes

Recovery: CWM

ROM: Stock

I am using Link2SD becuse my phone doesn't have much memory for apps and as such I had to partion my sd card, and for some reason my phone would only mount the last partion Not the First Partion so to combat this problem I partition my SD card the way shown below

SD Card Partion Layout:

1st: 7mb fat

2nd: 1.45GB Ext2

3rd: 13.45GB(around that) Fat (My main area were i want to backup my phone and were my music and photos go)

The Problem arises when I try to do a NANDroid Backup as CWM mounts the first partition and since it is so small it can not backup the phone.
I would like to be able to backup on the 3rd partition so

a) Is there a recovery that could do this

OR

b) If  Not how can I modifiy my recovery so I can

Comment: Matt it just looks complicated, just pay attention to detail and process and, always triple check. Here is LG Optimus L3 forum at XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/optimus-l3-l5-l7

Comment: @moonbutt74 I have already checked on XDA for this problem and have come up unsuccessful. The problem is that I want to do a NANDroid backup to my SD card but as told above I am unable to as I need the backup go to the second partition.

Comment: You have root and a custom recovery don't you? Dump the recovery.img , unpack it, make the edits, repack it.

Comment: Matt, how old is this phone? I am looking at the device=tree in cyanogenmod git and kernel source as well. I'll make a try at a philz build but we need to move to xda, stack isn't the place for this. Oh and the answer below does work, an upvote would be helpful. M xD

Comment: This phone is an Telstra Pre-Paid  LG Optimus L3, Running stock Gingerbread 2.3.6, I got it last year, Website: http://www.lg.com/au/support-mobile/lg-Optimus-L3-E400F
Release Dtae: 11/03/2013
And it has a officle cyangon nightly biuld created for it (Luck for users who use this phone)

Comment: okay link me to your custom recovery, or if you have it unpacked already you should just need to change the mmcblk1p# in you recovery.fstab to match the partition you want to back up to on your external sd card, so instead of the fstab entry being /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 it would be 1p3

Comment: I used Rasher to get a backup of my recover image. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5mtquWAP3MbTZUX05Qa2RMWlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Matt try this out, https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347794982 Don't lose your original, changed mmcblk1p1 to mmcblk1p3

Comment: If you just changed this "mmcblk1p1 " then why is it half its original size? I want to know before I use this as i don't want to skrew up my phone.

Comment: Matt , when you dump an image, unless specifying count the entire block get's dumped, so for example my boot.img is 8.9mb roughly but if i dump it using dd with specifying the proper count, I end up with a 10.1mb image, roughly, which is padding. When i unpack it and repack it i lose the padding and the image is again 8.9mb roughly , depending on modifications. You are certainly welcome to do as i suggested for yourself. If you have some question about my work, goto XDA. That being said, i did make it a point to tell you to keep your working img handy just in case. M.

Comment: Thanks for doing this for me. I was just wondering why it had gone done. As I nowhere at your skill level I obliviously didn't know that some of the space is 'padding'. Thanks.

Comment: The actual size of your ramdisk is roughly 2.2mb uncompressed and your kernel binary is rough 4.6mb in size - correction_ your kernel binary is 3.2mb

Comment: No prob, if you want to learn more goto XDA and setup an account and pm me by my user name I'll run you through the drill.

Comment: Okay that makes sense why it is so small. Am I able to use [Rasher] (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2334554) so if it doesn't work I can just reflash my original recovery?
And what did you use to unpack, edit and repack the recovery??

Comment: That i don't know, i do everything by the command line, just check out rashr's help menu or visit developer site, the image is in the same format. I've never used rashr so find out if there is a proper naming convention for the new image or not. Yes you can reflash your original recovery the same way you did the first time. Goto XDA and look up AIK by osm0sis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes,no,maybe. You might hit a snag with the fat/ext/fat scheme on your card but here goes,

I have a debian chroot `<ext4>` set up in

- /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 --> my extSdCard 2nd partition.

So i edit the following in my recovery ramdisk --> Philz Adv CWM

- init.rc --> add a directory export

under the `on init` section

```
export DEBIAN_ROOT /debian
```

- in etc/recovery.fstab of recovery ramdisk

  /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.2/by-num/p2              /debian      ext4    rw,errors=panic    wait

Remember this is cwm fstab format, adjust for twrp if needed! Your own device in regular operation will show you the right layout. Remember to set correct `<type>`for partition.

After you have all that done and have repacked and reflashed your recovery,

```
root@kali:/storage/tempus# adb reboot recovery
root@kali:/storage/tempus# adb shell mount /debian && adb shell mount | grep debian
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.2/by-num/p2 on /debian type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)


    root@kali:/storage/tempus# adb shell
    ~ # uname -a
    Linux localhost 3.4.0-Carmilla-mb74- #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 27 22:41:40 EST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
    ~ # ls /debian
    AIK         etc         lost+found  policy-k    sbin        t-src
    bin         home        media       proc        selinux     tmp
    boot        images      mnt         root        srv         usr
    dev         lib         opt         run         sys         var
    ~ #
```

I won't be going into the unpacking/repacking part of the procedure as i am sure that is covered elsewhere.

For a treat, i am still in recovery but exit back out to linux term because it's easier to mount system,

```
root@kali:/storage/tempus# adb shell mount /system
root@kali:/storage/tempus# adb shell
~ # go-deb
root@localhost:/# ls
AIK   dev   images      media  policy-k  run      srv    tmp
bin   etc   lib         mnt    proc      sbin     sys    usr
boot  home  lost+found  opt    root      selinux  t-src  var
root@localhost:/#
```

And after running my go-deb script after mounting /system i am now in my chroot while in recovery. No wifi though, i forgot to square away the modules.

Comment: This looks a little bit complicated but I will give it a try, but before that, your using PhilZ Touch and doing it with the terminal emulator right?
But my problem is I think there is no PhilZ Touch that can work on my Lg e400f unless you know were I can find it.